# Why UseBR doesn't work in highlight.js

Tags: javascript, highlight.js

I use highlight.js to highlight code syntax on a web page. I don't use `<pre><code>` but instead I use custom tag `<div class="code">` and I set `UseBr` (http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#configure-options) to use `<br>` instead of new lines. But it doesn't work for me..

```
hljs.configure({useBR: true});

$('div.code').each(function(i, block) {
  hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});
```

jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/s0gyounj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was a bug in highlight.js. Here's my issue report on GitHub https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/issues/860 and the good news is that it fixed!

UPDATE:

You should have <br> in the input to preserve it in the output with help of this option.